# Apache mod_substitute not working with Javascript

Tags: apache

Tried below config to substitute backend url in javascript using mod_substitute but not working so far.

```
    <VirtualHost *:7070>
      ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.101:9090/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.101:9090/
      <Location />
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/plain
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/xml
        Substitute "s|http://192.168.0.101:9090|http://172.24.101.121:7070|i"
      </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything incorrect as it is working for plain html page but not for javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding:

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE x-application/javascript
```